# How do I use a file that I coded and get the information onto my console(has ints and strings)

Tags: java, file

I hava created this file with strings and ints. How can I get that information by calling on the file so I can create another file with new information using the original data and print new data on my console?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Project3 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Grades g = new Grades();
        g.openFile();
        g.addRecords();
        g.closeFile
    }
}
```

//my Grades class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Grades {

    private  Formatter x;
    //Formatter variable- output string to file

    public void openFile(){
    //method to open file
        try{
            x = new Formatter("grades.txt");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not find file.");
        }
    }

    public void addRecords(){
        x.format("%s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d", "Joe", "Shmoe", 100, 90, 80, 100);
        x.format("%s %s, %d, %d, %d", "\Hardy B.", "Boy", 90, 90, 100);
        x.format("%s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\Jeff", "Johnson",  70, 78, 80);
    }

public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i assume you have issue in reading a text file and printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BufferedReader to read content from file.

```
BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file name"));
```

Read line by line from file and print it in console.

```
while ((currentLine = breader.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(currentLine);
```

}

if you just want to print this would be fine.
if you want to process it like reading integer and changing it.

you need to then use **Scanner**. To know about scanner checkout this
[Oracle scanner tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html).

Comment: How exactly would you use the Scanner to process the integers(ex. add all them up?)

Answer (score 0):

This will print to console while making a duplicate file.

```
private static void copyFileUsingFileStreams(File source, File dest)
    throws IOException {
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;
try {
    input = new FileInputStream(source);
    output = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
        output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        System.out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} finally {
    input.close();
    output.close();
}
}
```